# Execution order issue in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React/Redux app that features a date picker.

Here's the simplified version of my code:

```
handleChangeDate(date) {

   // First, I set the new date in my redux store
   this.props.actions.setDate(date);

   // Check some condition
   if(a !== b) {

      // I then call a callback function that is passed as a prop from the parent component
      return this.props.someCallBackFunction();
   }

}
```

Here's what's happening:

- Initially everything works fine
- Once I set the new date, the `someCallBackFunction()` seems to be firing first which pulls the active date from the store and makes an API call. But because the date hasn't changed yet, I get the same data as before I initiated the date change
- When I change the date once more, the same things are happening as I described above but it now uses the date from previous step.

In other words, the execution order is reverse so I always end up getting a data set for the date I set in my previous action.

Any idea what may be causing this and how to fix it?

P.S. The callback function gets the active date from the redux store which is why I'm not passing it. I like the idea of using the redux store as the single source of truth but I somehow need to fix the execution order issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the case, it doesn't seem like you should be handling the callback inside of this handler. Have you considered using the lifecycle method `componentWillUpdate()` ?

Take a look at the first few examples here, they might help.

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/tapping_into_componentwillupdate.html

Comment: Very interesting! I've never used `componentWillUpdate()` before. I just did a quick and dirty update and it seems to be getting the correct date now. I just need to digest this new concept. I don't run into this issue very often and to be honest, I don't know why I'm having it now. At a glance, using `componentWillUpdate()` seems like a solid idea because it's based on a definite event so moving some logic in there seems like a good idea. On the other hand, I'm wondering why the execution order is unpredictable -- or predictable but I don't get it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I think it all comes back to the fact that nothing will wait for your store to update unless you explicitly use a lifecycle method to do so. Your source of truth needs to speak to the component in the pre-defined ways, and putting a callback like that inside of an event handler is just asking for a disconnect between what the state currently has and what you're looking to receive back. The state does take a split second to update, it's not like updating a variable within the same function.

Comment: One thing is for sure: learning about `componentWillUpdate()` -- thanks to you -- is great.